# Fixing for warning TRCH1115 using EnsureTable element

Tags: wix, wix3.7

We have a bunch of 3rd party merge modules attached to our WiX installer and during the build we get a bunch of TRCH1115 warnings. I was looking at [Trying to use EnsureTable in WiX to fix Validation Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461907/trying-to-use-ensuretable-in-wix-to-fix-validation-errors).

But in this article the warnings/errors that they see for the Validation errors refer to the table that has the validation error. In my case the only table that it mentions is the _validation table it self. So if I am going to try an use the EnsureTable element to fix for these warnings then how would I go about finding out what table Id I should be using in the EnsureTable element?

The warnings I gets look like the following:

> warning TRCH1115: The value '0' in table '_Validation', column
>   'KeyColumn' is invalid according to the column's validation
>   information. The decompiled output includes a best-effort
>   representation of this value.

Thanks for any help on this issue.

Comment: Okay using Orca I found the tables that are giving these _Validation warnings are ISComonentExtented and ISCustomActionReference.

If I use the EnsureTable elements for these I will get the following errors during build:
error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixCustomTable:ISComponentExtended' in section 'Product:{5750E980-27F9-452A-A86D-5D2610639FEE}
error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixCustomTable:ISCustomActionReference' in section 'Product:{5750E980-27F9-452A-A86D-5D2610639FEE}'
So can I use EnsureTable to identify IS tables that are in merge modules built by IS?